# How to create a Chromadb after VectorstoreIndexCreator for your CSV?

Tags: python, excel, csv, embedding, chromadb

I have successfully created a chatbot that can answer question by referencing to the csv. My code is as below,

```
loader = CSVLoader(file_path='data.csv') # load the csv
index_creator = VectorstoreIndexCreator() # initiation
docsearch = index_creator.from_loaders([loader]) # embedding
```

My chain is as follow,

```
chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=OpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0), chain_type="stuff", retriever=docsearch.vectorstore.as_retriever(), input_key="question")
```

Everything is perfect so far.

But I am trying to create an app which will solve problems by referencing to this csv, therefore I would like to store the vectorized data into a chromadb which can be retrieved without embedding again.

I understand that (please tell me if I am wrong) docsearch.vectorstore is already a chromadb. When I `print(docsearch.vectorstore)`, it returns,

```
<langchain_community.vectorstores.chroma.Chroma object at 0x13e079130>
```

But how do it store it as a file? Like that you would do after embedding a txt or pdf file, you persist it in a folder.

```
embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=openai_api_key)
# embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=openai_api_key, model_name='text-embedding-3-small')

persist_directory = "embedding/chroma"

# Create a Chroma vector database for the current states after embedding
vectordb = Chroma(
    persist_directory = persist_directory,
    embedding_function = embedding)
vectordb.persist() 

database = Chroma.from_documents(doc, embedding=embedding, persist_directory = persist_directory)
```

Then you will be able find the database file in the persist_directory.

So, my question is, how do I achieve a similar process with my csv data? I have googled, e.g. [Is there any way to load an index created through VectorstoreIndexCreator in langchain? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76174236/is-there-any-way-to-load-an-index-created-through-vectorstoreindexcreator-in-lan)
But it seems not the answer. Because the answer calls the "docs" and "embeddings", which I can't seem to find those in the op,.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```py
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=docsearch.vectorstore.as_retriever(),
    # input_key="question"
)

print(chain.invoke("question"))
```